# Получить доступ к элементам веб формы webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Собственно, есть веб страница, внутри который еще как бы одна в окошке, и обычные методы например `_driver.FindElementById("spriteAnimation2").Click();` не действуют, так как нет доступа к элементам этого встроенного браузера, или же не может найти их[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить доступ к кнопке SEARCH

Comment: Вы имеете в виду Frame?

Comment: Может быть, <iframe id="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
  _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElementById("<IFRAME_ID>"));
  _driver.FindElementById("spriteAnimation2").Click();
```

Comment: в общем сначала нужно переключить webdriver "смотреть" на iframe, а после уже искать элементы, которые расположены во фрейме